# Paypal refunding a split transaction

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I have built the paypal's parallel payment option into my website. Here a % goes into my website paypal account and remaining goes into one of the merchant's paypal account. When i need to issue refunds, how can i make it work where both my portion and merchants portion are refunded automatically? I tried the paypal refund APIs but it only works for my portion, but for the merchants portion it says i dont have permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have the other merchant's that you are splitting the payment with, grant API permissions to your API to be able to issue refunds.  Otherwise, you would not be able to issue refunds from their account with your credentials.

Comment: Wow, this is one answer i was looking for.

Comment: Is there a SOAP API for setting permissions? All i see is the NVP code sample. Although i dont see any sample SOAP code on the internet, i think i can use SetAccessPermissionsRequestType, but i dont know which API to call in 



SetAccessPermissionsResponseType ppresponse = (SetAccessPermissionsResponseType) caller
     .call("?", pprequest);